# Create ListView programmatically

Tags: android, listview

Hi I am new in Android. Could anyone tell me pls whats the wrong with the following code:

```
public class ListApp extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView lText = new TextView(this);
        lText.setId(0);       

        ListView lView = new ListView(this);
        String[] lStr = new String[]{"AA","BB", "CC"};
        ArrayAdapter lAdap = new ArrayAdapter(this,lText.getId(),lStr);
        lView.setAdapter(lAdap);
        lView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);        

        setContentView(lView);
    }
}
```

Comment: for one thing, you're using the ArrayAdapter constructor incorrectly.  you want to use the two parameter version: (Context context, int textViewResourceId)

Comment: like this: ArrayAdapter<String> lAdap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, lText.getId());

Answer (score 23):

here's a solution that does not require you to write any xml layouts.  it uses standard android layouts where possible and no inflation is necessary:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Select Color Mode");

ListView modeList = new ListView(this);
String[] stringArray = new String[] { "Bright Mode", "Normal Mode" };
ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, stringArray);
modeList.setAdapter(modeAdapter);

builder.setView(modeList);
dialog = builder.create();
```

Comment: ignore the dialog stuff.  you can adapt this to work with a ListActivity as well.

Comment: I copied your code exactly but no listview is generated.

Comment: sorry i got it now, your code is missing dialog.show();

Answer (score 4):

Try this..

Paste the following code in list_item.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" 
    android:textSize="16sp" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textStyle="bold" android:background="@drawable/border_cell">
</TextView>
```

Here is the activity class....

```
    public class UsersListActivity extends ListActivity{    
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
            String[] statesList = {"listItem 1", "listItem 2", "listItem 3"};
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,
                    statesList)); 
            ListView lv = getListView(); 

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {


                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                     "You selected : "+((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
            });

        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to separate view (xml layout) and controller (Activity).

If you dont want this, try to put

```
 setContentView(lView);
```

at the beginning of ***onCreate***

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ListApp extends ListActivity
```

Comment: Could I add ListView form Activity. I don't want to inherit from ListActiviy. Is it possible?

Comment: I have the same issue, porting a project from iPhone and Blackberry and using Android's XML is a redesign... argh.  If it's easy to procedurally create these things it would make life soooo much easier and looks like it should be possible but hey I'm still new to Android :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a layout XML file with your listview and use findViewById to set it's adapter after first setting the content view to your layout